# How to unit test a JMS listener in spring boot?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, mockrunner

I want to write unit test for a method which is annotated by `@JmsListener`. But I don't know how to do it. Anybody please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing tests to verify received msg in jms listener (Spring-Boot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803627/writing-tests-to-verify-received-msg-in-jms-listener-spring-boot)

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example of your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve