# Unable to unit test a @KafkaListener annotated method

Tags: spring, unit-testing, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to unit test a kafka consumer class, in Spring. I want to know that if a kafka message is sent to it's topic, the listener method was called correctly. My consumer class is annotated like this:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topics.myTopic}")
public void myKafkaMessageEvent(final String message) { ...
```

If I @Autowire a consumer, when I send a kafka message, the listener method is called correctly, but I can't assert that the method was called because the class isn't a mock.

If I mock a consumer, when I send a kafka message the listener method is not called at all. I can call the method directly, and assert that it worked, but that doesn't do what I want, which is to check if the method is called when I send a kafka message to it's topic.

For now I have resorted to put a counter inside the consumer, and increment it every time the listener method is called, then check that it's value has been changed. Making a variable just for testing seems like a terrible solution to me.

Is there maybe a way to make the mocked consumer receive the kafka messages too? Or some other way to assert that the non-mocked consumer listener method was called?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are requesting something similar what we have in Spring AMQP Testing Framework: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#test-harness

So, if you are not good with extra variable you can borrow that [solution](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/tree/master/spring-rabbit-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/test) and implement your own "harness".

I think that should be a good addition to the Framework so, please, raise an appropriate [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues) and we can together bring such a tool for the public.

**UPDATE**

So, according Spring AMQP foundation I did this in my test configuration:

```
public static class KafkaListenerTestHarness extends KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor {

    private final Map<String, Object> listeners = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void processListener(MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint endpoint, KafkaListener kafkaListener,
            Object bean, Object adminTarget, String beanName) {

        bean = Mockito.spy(bean);

        this.listeners.put(kafkaListener.id(), bean);

        super.processListener(endpoint, kafkaListener, bean, adminTarget, beanName);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T getSpy(String id) {
        return (T) this.listeners.get(id);
    }

}

...

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Bean(name = KafkaListenerConfigUtils.KAFKA_LISTENER_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME)
@Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
public static KafkaListenerTestHarness kafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new KafkaListenerTestHarness();
}
```

Then in the target test-case I use it like this:

```
@Autowired
private KafkaListenerTestHarness harness;
...
Listener listener = this.harness.getSpy("foo");

verify(listener, times(2)).listen1("foo");
```

Comment: There `KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` to process all those `@KafkaListener` methods. You just need to follow a `RabbitListenerTestHarness` logic. Let me show something simple in my answer a bit later!

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit confused... So I have this: `@Autowired private TestConfig.KafkaListenerTestHarness harness;` and this: `@Autowired private ReceiveMessageRetrievedEventHandler receiver;` The second is my consumer with the listener method. How would I use your code here? And the `foo` parameter I also don't get... I appreciate the help, sorry I'm having some difficult with this...

Comment: Pay attention how I store the `spy` - into the `KafkaListenerTestHarness .listeners` `Map`. And only this way you can get access to the `spy`. The `foo` is an `id()` on the `@KafkaListener`. See what I get for the map key in the `KafkaListenerTestHarness`.

Comment: I think I understand... But I'm getting a `Another endpoint is already registered with id` error now that I can't get rid of...

Comment: I am, I only use this id in one place: `@KafkaListener( topic ... id = "ReceiveMessageProductRetrievedEventHandlerID")
public void productRetrievedEvent(final ProductTransaction message) {`

And then in my test:
`@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class ... ReceiveMessageProductRetrievedEventHandler.class})`

`@Autowired private TestConfig.KafkaListenerTestHarness harness;`
The error happens if this line on the harness is run:
`super.processListener(endpoint, kafkaListener, bean, adminTarget, beanName);` If I comment it it goes away.

Comment: It does not. `Wanted but not invoked`. on here: `verify(listener, times(1)).productRetrievedEvent(anyObject());`. And, I had a breakpoint on the listener, it was indeed called. I'm gonna read all this code again, see if I'm missing something...

Comment: I realize I'm not using your `kafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor()` anywhere, it's just there... Is that right?

Comment: I don't understand your last question. The `kafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor()` is a bean which just has to be declared there.

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, then you should abandon such a solution and go some other way. Also I've already asked you to raise an appropriate GH issue on the matter and we definitely will do something in the Framework for these use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the bean that will be exercised in the spring context refresh can not be mocked. If you want to mock this bean like kafkaListener, just use the @SpyBean annotation.  You can find more in this github issue of the spring boot. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16324